# Если в цепочке наследования 3 класса, должен ли деструктор второго быть virtual?

Tags: c++, ооп

Если в цепочке наследования 3 класса, должен ли деструктор второго быть virtual?

Comment: Как обычно: В одних сценариях - должен, в других - нет.

Comment: в том случае, если мы будем использовать объект класса 3 через указатель на объект класса 2

Comment: Виртуальный деструктор понадобится, только когда владение объектом класса 3 идет через указатель на объект класса 2.

Comment: Вы можете не объявлять его виртуальным, но компилятор сделает его виртуальным сам, увидев виртуальный декструктор предка.

Comment: Если виртуальный деструктор уже есть у предка, то в этом классе деструктор следует объявить как `override`.